# Weekly password change?

Tags: passwords, password-management, cpanel

I want an app that will change all server password for me on a weekly basis (whm and cpanel) and allow for an easy way for admins to get this new password each week. (I want to tighten security).

I use WHM and cPanel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tighten security, then don't share a password among more than one person.

Create new reseller accounts for each admin, with full access and have them use their own account to login.

Then use the `chage` command on each account to set the warning days and maximum days before a password change is required.

Comment: But can WHM have multiple root password? This is specifically for root of a server and more than one admin requires root on a regular basis.

Comment: If they need root to carry out WHM type activties then a reseller with maximum permissions can do this.  You can also add them to the wheel group to give them sudo permissions.